# How can I use getopts in bash and have it work with an extra flag?

Tags: bash, getopts

I want to mock the verbose command in rm this is what I currently have

```
while getopts ":ehrm" opt; do . 
case ${opt} in . 
e ) empty . 
;;
```

there is more, but it's just the other options such as h,r,and m. what I want to do is allow the user to do something like.

-m -v in the command line arguments where v is suppose to mock verbose.

the -m fully works, and goes to the m section and executes that line, but how can I also incorporate and check if -v exists as well in the same line not its own stand alone flag

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have `.` at the end of each line?

Comment: Each option should just set a variable. After the loop, you execute code that uses each variable to modify the behavior.